File version in File Explorer for .NET 8 application
I have .NET 8 application and in .csproj file:
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows7.0</TargetFramework>
   <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <FileVersion>2.0.0</FileVersion>
   <AssemblyVersion>2.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
   <Version>2.0.0</Version>  
 </PropertyGroup>

So what I expect to see in Windows File Explorer as File Version - something like 2.0.0 or 2.0.0.0. But instead I see for File Version and Product Version 0.0.0.0.
I tried different formats for csproj properties like 2.0.0.0 or 2.0.0 but nothing changes Explorer zeroes.
Any advise how to set properties for File Explorer?
(It seems the problem appeared after project upgrade from .NET Framework to .NET 8, I can't reproduce it in a standalone .NET 8 project).

Which OS are you building on?

@MartinUllrich Windows 11

My solution was to delete the generated line of the upgrade process (or enabling):
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>

In the project folder file (*.csproj). Afterwards, delete the obj folder within the solution project.

Apparently the generation does not refer to the project level, as I assumed when I first saw the line, but to an artifact of the build, which is then located in the mentioned obj folder and finally used for the exe/dll compilation.
